# How to call describe function with chunk in pandas?

Tags: pandas, large-files

I'm working on a large csv file ( over 4GB).

So I have to work on chunks of pandas( leak memory)

But I don't know how to take describe( count,min, max, percentile,...) of whole data.

Please give me some advice for this issue

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a csv file, you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

nr_chunk_size = 10
summary = []
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=nr_chunk_size)
for chunck in df:
    summary.append(chunck.describe().values)
```

Afterwards, you need to aggregate the `summary` list. The count should be easy, you just need to sum it up such as,

```
count = sum([summary[i][0][0] for i in range(len(summary))])
```

, for min and max, you need to create a list of all the numbers and take the minimum number,

```
minimum = min([summary[i][3][0] for i in range(len(summary))])
maximum = max([summary[i][7][0] for i in range(len(summary))])
```

For the percentile, it's a little bit difficult as you don't take the entire dataset into it. You could just take the average of the percentile which is an approximate.

Comment: Average of the percentile is not approximation for real percentile. And could you have any better solution for thar? I know your solution for count, max, min but it's really not convinient

Comment: Yeh it's not really an approximate;) I just needed a wording for this. If you already know the solution for count, max and min, why didn't you write this in your question...

Comment: Because, I think It's not really good. I want to find solution to inherit from built-in describe at least code. And i think my code that not really good. It's not to difficult to use sum/max/min for each chunk and summary all. Could you realize that?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I gave you my vote. But I really need better solution. If you know, please show me